# react + jest pass setup environment to subcomponent

Tags: reactjs, testing, webpack, jestjs, externals

I am trying to set up test for my react app  using jest and enzyme.
I have a component `<DetailView>` which depending on what kind of media it receives renders a different child component. 
Like

```
render(){
var media;
var fileEnding = this.props.data.asset[0].DocumentInfo.FileExtension;
  switch(fileEnding){
    case "mp3":

            media = <Audio>
            break;
 case "obj": 
          media = <ThreeDView>
          break
....}

return(
  <Col lg={6}>
      {media}
    </Col>
)};
```

One of them is using threejs. 
I include threejs in my index.html like so

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

and in webpack via externals

```
externals: {       
    "three":"THREE",
    "OrbitControls":"THREE.OrbitControls",
    "Detector": "Detector",
```

When I now mount the `<DetailView>` component in my test, it fails with the message:

```
FAIL  __tests__/DetailViewBeahviour.spec.js Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module 'Detector' from 'ThreeDView.js'
```

I have tried to add it via the `setup` file:

```
global.Detector = require('three/examples/js/Detector');
console.log(global.Detector);
```

Which gives me this output

```
console.log setup/setup.js:2
{ canvas: false,
  webgl: false,
  workers: false,
  fileapi: [Function: Blob],
  getWebGLErrorMessage: [Function: getWebGLErrorMessage],
  addGetWebGLMessage: [Function: addGetWebGLMessage] }
```

But I still cant mount the component, same Error, so I assume, its not available inside the `<ThreeDView>` component.
I looked at the manual mock example but again dont understand how to make it accessible to the subcomponent.

Any hints are much appreciated